# How to disable E_STRICT

Tags: php

I need to turn off E_STRICT. I have error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT in my php.ini but it seems to be ignored. I tried this in my code:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_NOTICE);
```

Nothing!

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that your php.ini file is not being over-riden somewhere else? Is there a more local version of the php.ini file?

Comment: Instead of turning off errors, you should actually rather fix your code so it won't even throw anything..

Comment: poke: I know that thanks, but I have a framework too, the app is in production and is ok and I do not have the time!

Comment: @rtacconi: "Nothing!" - you wrote, but you didn't mention what kind of errors you got. Are you sure it's related to the `E_STRICT` error reporting?

Comment: Is it possible that your framework is using ini_set and adding E_STRICT back in later on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

This will report all errors except E_STRICT

Answer (score 5):

If you've got your own error handler (search your code for `set_error_handler`), then the `error_reporting` config value will be ignored:

> It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types unless the callback function returns FALSE. **error_reporting() settings will have no effect** and your error handler will be called regardless - however you are still able to read the current value of error_reporting and act appropriately. Of particular note is that this value will be 0 if the statement that caused the error was prepended by the @ error-control operator.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Also removing `E_STRICT` from the `error_reporting` config could fail, if the error occurs in the same file where `error_reporting(...)` (or `ini_set('error_reporting, ...')`) is called.

Comment: +1 because this was the answer that helped me most here. I created a hook class called ExceptionHook in CodeIgniter which calls an error handler like this:

   `set_error_handler(array('ExceptionHook', 'exception_error_handler'), E_ALL);` If I pass E_STRICT to the second argument, a key legacy library fails so I needed to switch off E_STRICT errors.

Comment: agree, most helpful one. Internet is full of ^/~E_STRICT things but my issue was in error_handler.. cool!

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you're using a framework (would be good to know which one) anyway you can add something like this on the very first index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

But make sure you're on the first index.php that gets called, meaning the very first in the stack, for certain framework that would save you some pain.

Other thing: most of the frameworks have their own config file to address production software VS. development software and they have their own way of doing things, so I would start from there....have a look at the docs and find out if there's anything there you need to change...it could be a super simple change on a config file most likely.

Answer (score 1):

I was installing CMS Made simple when I ran into that error but here is how I over came it:

1) Open your php.ini file using any of your favorite editors;notepad, notepad++ or dreamweaver.

2) Press ctrl+f to fire up the find Dialog Box.

3) Type E_STRICT and click ok to jump you to the E_STRICT Line, there several E_STRICT Stuff but look for one with this kind of setting;

Common Values:

```
E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices)
   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
   E_ALL | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
 Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
 Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
 Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
 http://php.net/error-reporting
```

*error_reporting* =  **E_ALL** , here the value with out the ";" is what matters so I just cleared it to:

*error_reporting* = (delete) and removed the **E_ALL**, and saved the file, I restarted all the services, and everything worked fine.
Hope that works for you too!.

Answer (score -2):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```