# AJAX called files displaying errors when error_reporting=off

Tags: error-handling, php, error-reporting

In `php.ini`, my error display settings are as follows:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
display_errors  = Off
```

which works for any normally called file, however, if a file is called using jQuery/AJAX, I receive errors such as:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method XML_Util::replaceEntities() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/lib/php/XML/Util.php on line 664
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method XML_Util::createTagFromArray() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/site/public_html/site/paypal/lib/Serializer/Serializer.php on line 1231
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method XML_Util::attributesToString() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /usr/lib/php/XML/Util.php on line 652

As can be assumed, this is breaking parts of my website, how can I fix this?

I am running PHP 5.4.10

The files are being called using Jquery functions: `$.get` or `$.post`

Comment: Where is `display_errors = Off` set from? If it's not in the `ini`, it should be at all relevant entry-points (or in the front-controller)

Comment: Did you set it in the correct php.ini?  Check the output of `phpinfo()` or `php -i` to see _which_ php.ini is being called.

Comment: Unrelated but why the hell would you disable `E_NOTICE`? If you get notices it usually means your code is bad and should be fixed...

Comment: @ThiefMaster This is for the production site, errors are on for the dev/test site.

Comment: Even in production you should keep E_NOTICE enabled - just with display_errors=off and errors going to syslog.

Answer (score 1):

The code/library you are using is triggering a *Strict Standards* error/notice/warning.

The related error-reporting constant for it is called [`E_STRICT`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/errorfunc.constants) which was [introduced in PHP 5.0<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/migrating5.errorrep).

Since PHP 5.4 `E_STRICT` is part of `E_ALL`, so it has to be removed from it as  well if you configure the way you do:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So if you exclude `E_STRICT` from your production error settings, these *Strict Standards* errors should not be logged any longer - which would be probably like you would have had it with your earlier PHP 5.3 version.

Additionally you should contact the vendor of the library and request to make the code *`E_STRICT` compatible*. This is good practice and also shows you that some code has a certain quality.

For your development you should equally make your code `E_STRICT` compatible, fixing any place that is causing a *Strict Standards* error.

Same applies to `E_NOTICE` and `E_DEPRECATED`, you should enable these messages in your development environment and fix all the reported problems. This saves you from getting more and more bugs too easily.

From the `php.ini`:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Quick Reference ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; The following are all the settings which are different in either the production
; or development versions of the INIs with respect to PHP's default behavior.
; Please see the actual settings later in the document for more details as to why
; we recommend these changes in PHP's behavior.

...

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

The reason why you see the error messages outputted instead of logged is not clear from the information you provide in your question. This can have multiple reasons,

- most straight forward because you have not properly disabled display of errors - or enabled it again in the runtime (that setting can be changed from within PHP code, too).
- error display *is* disabled but there is [some error handler<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/function.set-error-handler) that is displaying them anyway.

So apart from the error level setting, this part of your question requires more trouble-shooting on your end to find out why the error messages are being displayed.

---

*See Also:*

- [How to disable E_STRICT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2851004/367456) (17 May 2010; by rtacconi)
- [Error Reporting - PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting)