# dont show E_E_STRICT with error reporting

Tags: php, error-reporting

I want to hide E_STRICT warning with `error_reproting` , my php version is 5.4 
I try this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

I also try

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

and

```
error_reporting(E_ALL^ E_STRICT );
```

and

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE ^ E_STRICT ^E_WARNING);
```

**but I still see the E_STRICT warning ,why it not applied?**

**what is the problem and how can I fix it?**

**my php version 5.4**

Comment: have youtried this? error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT); check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851004/how-to-disable-e-strict

Comment: @MazIqbal But also I want dont show warning and notice, I try 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_STRICT ^ E_WARNING); but not work !!!

Comment: What is your environtment?

Comment: Try this http://www.bx.com.au/tools/ultimate-php-error-reporting-wizard?php_version=5_4

Answer (score 1):

Before 5.4

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

After 5.4 when E_STRICT became part of E_ALL

```
error_reporting('E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE');
```

Comment: I test it , php 5.4  5.4.0  E_STRICT became part of E_ALL. !!! look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @zhilevan Just remove the quotes like in the first code snippet.

Comment: I test E_ERROR , It also cotaints E_STRICT warning