# PHP 5.6 error_reporting setting in .ini file not working

Tags: php

I'm sure the answer is out there, I haven't figured out the correct combination of words to search on to find it.  Note: this is not a noob "how do I avoid looking up the answer myself" question, I've been working with PHP long enough that I know how this is *supposed* to work.  It just doesn't work in this case for as-yet unknown reasons.  Been working on this for enough hours that I need to stop & ask.

PHP 5.6.3 on Windows 2012, upgraded from 5.3 where there was no problem (I know, I know, E_STRICT is included in E_ALL as of 5.4, keep reading)

php.ini has:

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

...but the Strict Standards errors still appear (Only variables should be assigned by reference, Non-static method should not be called statically, etc.).

In php.ini, changing the value of display_errors from "On" to "Off" removes all the errors & notices, so I know I'm editing the correct php.ini file, but I need them on for dev so can't just hide everyting.  The error_reporting() function is not modifying the setting anywhere in code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable E\_STRICT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851004/how-to-disable-e-strict)

Comment: Not really - I'm asking why error_reporting in php.ini is not having the desired effect when the error reporting is not being changed anywhere in code.

Comment: Deleting my answer until I can do research on it tomorrow.

Comment: If you call `error_reporting() ` immediately after setting it, do you get back the same value you set?

Comment: error_reporting() says 22527, which is E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED, and yet the strict standards errors remain

Comment: It's become a moot point, the plugin that created the need to upgrade to 5.6 has been switched out for a different one that works in 5.3, but if I ever figure this out I'll post the answer.